# Difference between monthly loan payment formula and compound interest formula

Tags: finance

The formula to calculate monthly loan payments (i.e. for [fixed-rate mortgage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-rate_mortgage)) is $(P r)/(1-(1+r)^{-N})$ where $P$ is the principal, $r$ is the monthly interest rate, and $N$ is the number of monthly payments.

What is the difference between this equation and using the equation for compound interest:
Monthly payment = $(P(1+(i/12))^N)/N$ where $P$ is the principal, $N$ is the number of monthly payments, and $i$ is the annual interest rate?

Apologies for the formatting of equations.

Comment: Where did you get the second formula from?

Comment: Nowhere... I used the formula for compound interest = P(1+i)^N

Comment: OK. But your formula for compound interest computes the future value of an initial investment of P. Whereas the other formula computes how large monthly payments have to be to pay back a principal of P. Two different beasts really.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks. If this is the case, what would the formula I gave:  (P(1+(i/12))N)/N calculate?

Comment: You just divided up the future value of P in N equal parts. Doesn't really mean much more than that.